# Recommendations for RSS modules

Tags: module, packages, rss

I am currently looking into which RSS modules are available for Sitecore. While doing so, I was wondering what the  recommended module(s) are, and what I should be looking out for when deciding which RSS module to use.

**Edit**:
I would like to be able to use the module to create both RSS feeds from my own items and have them accessible from the outside, but also consume other RSS feeds from different online sources and present them on different pages in my solution (insertable as a rendering). As for the presentation goes I would like it to be fairly easy to change the look and feel of this, possible without any (or at least minimal) developer involvement. I am using MVC, so the RSS feed module should work with this as well.

Comment: You mean other than the built-in RSS functionality?  Could you clarify what features you are looking for?

Comment: @MarkCassidy I've updated the requirements for what I need in my question. It might very well be that all can be achieved by using the built-in Sitecore RSS functionalities. I haven't used it that much before, but since there are a few existing RSS modules in the marketplace, I was wondering if these would be preferred to use instead.

Comment: Instead of asking for modules, I would re-phrase your question(s) around what you want to achieve (each feature should be its own paragraph, if now its own question) - You'll get module recommendations if that's the answer, or snippets if that's the solution. As written, this question is tough to answer.

Comment: @SergeantSitecore That makes perfectly good sense. How should I close this question, with the intention of creating more specifies questions?

Comment: Create your new questions, then reference them in the answer to this question.

Comment: @SergeantSitecore Got it - will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gonna take a stab at this. I'm not sure a module is what you're looking for, at least not for recent versions of Sitecore.  At least for providing RSS feeds of Item specific content. Plus, you are really asking for two very different functionalities.

### Rendering of Sitecore Specific Content Items as an RSS Feed

For Sitecore 8, you can use the built in RSS Feed generation utility to create your own RSS feeds of Sitecore based items. There is a [very in-depth walk-through on Sitecore's Documentation Site for this](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/the_editing_tools/the_content_editor/subscribe_to_a_client_rss_feed).

### Displaying External RSS Feeds as a Rendering Component

I'm, not sure that there's really any great modules out there on the Marketplace to solve this issue. However, what comes to mind is the uniqueness of how one might present and render the RSS feed would become very dependent on client guidelines and branding requirements.  So, this solution might not be something that works great as a third party module.

Having said that, I think that .NET provides some pretty nifty tools for dealing with external RSS feeds through the `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` library. There's a pretty [extensive demo on how to utilize this on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/steveres/2008/01/20/using-syndicationfeed-to-display-photos-from-spaces-live-com/).

I think with just a little bit of elbow grease, you can take this example demo and come up with a component to render an external RSS feed. In an MVC scenario, you can seed the model with the data as a collection of SyndicationItem's.

Hope this helps!